# Trying to open a certain filetype using my python exe

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I made a simple python file encryptor. I want to open all encrypted (or .aes) files using my program. I have already made it into a working executable using pyinstaller but when I tried to open a .aes file with my program (through the context menu in the file explorer), it unsurprisingly started the program but did not take the .aes file as input. I want to open any .aes file using my program and for the python script to somehow get the filepath as a variable. Is there any way of doing this when working with pyinstaller?

I want something like:

```
if isencrypted(filepath): 
    decrypt(filepath)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name will be passed as a command line argument. You need

```
import sys
filepath = sys.argv[1]
```